# turbolinks with masonry is not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-masonry, turbolinks

I have installed turbolink gem https://github.com/rails/turbolinks in my rails app 3.2.8.

I use this gem, masonry for show elements https://github.com/desandro/masonry.

The problem is that masonry elements when I open a new page with turbolinks are not loaded correctly.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The problem was fixed with https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks thank you

Comment: I have this problem too, now that Turbolinks is included with Rails 4. I don't think this is that localized.

Comment: I agree, not localized.