# Turbolinks makes page loaded blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I think it is Turbolinks causing this issue, but if I am on my `root_path` while logged in and go to a bunch of different pages and come back to my `root_path` and the bulk of the main part of the page doesn't show.

The log shows that all the elements are loaded, when I view source I see all of the elements - but it just doesn't show up on the page on the 2nd load of the `root_path`.

This is my `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require best_in_place
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place.purr
//= require bootstrap.file-input
//= require chosen.jquery
//= require spin.min
//= require ladda.min
//= require masonry.js
//= require main.js
//= require intro.js 
//= require turbolinks

$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Activating Best In Place && Include Success Highlighting & Bounce for comments & videos */
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place().bind("ajax:success", function () {$(this).closest('p, h5').effect('highlight').effect("bounce", { times:3 },  { duration:400}).dequeue(); });
});

$(document).on("page:load ready", function(){
    $("input.datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

In my `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I even tried adding this to my `application.js` but it still doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: IMHO just uninstall turbolinks

Comment: @Richlewis I want the benefits of turbolinks. It really does make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is masonry library. And it's still not figured out

[turbolinks with masonry is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256649/turbolinks-with-masonry-is-not-working).

You may use grid from any css framework or use EX http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ which works with infinite scroll too :)